# Посчитать количество разных ip с запросов?

Tags: php

Есть страница на котрою поступают post запросы.
Как можно вести счет сколько разных ip адресов обращается по этому адресу?
Можно сохранять все ip адреса в один массив в файле txt либо в базу данных MySQL как можно реализовать такую функцию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно получать адрес каждого посетителя из `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];` и сохранять его в базу данных, попутно при каждом посещении вызывать функцию которая будет проверять, существует ли такой адрес в базе, если нет, то добавлять